# Non standard URL response with '#' in place of '?'

Tags: onelogin

It looks like OneLogin add #error=xxxx in place of ?error=xxxx when something is wrong. I do not have this issue when no error.

I wanted to warn user about configuration error. Unfortunatly because of the '#' my server base on libmicrohttpd does not parse correctly the url query.

any idea ?

```
https://localhost:1234/sgate/onelogin/login#error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=unsupported%20response_type%20requested&state=2f886384-4c57-4c9a-a933-ef989bf26385&ol_oidc_issuer_url=https%3A%2F%2Fiot-bzh-dev.onelogin.com%2Foidc%2F2
```

Comment: You are using OIDC Implicit flow. All OP send their response in this fashion only, you need to differentiate response from # and then decode the rest of the string.

Comment: I support many different authorities and this is the only case where I get a '#' in the response. The OIDC redirect is designed to be handle by the server not by the browser and an unfortunately traditional HTTP server cannot process a url with a '#' because this is not part of URL spec.

Comment: Correct. What worked for me was, getting the URL in string and splitting with #. After that I just decoded and got the data

Comment: Along with that, your response is not valid and server is sending error. Make sure your SSO flow also works.